# can eth_call simulate approve and transfer?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, web3.py, solidity-0.8.x

I have a solidity contract that contains a logic to approve and transfer balance, swap and flashloan. But when i use `eth_call` to call my function that perform swap, it reverts.

I tried by `eth_sendRawTransaction`, and it gives me the correct result. so My question is, Can `eth_call` simulate transaction that contain `safeapprove` and `transfer` or do I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `eth_estimateGas`. It will run your code without executing it and estimate the cost. It will also tell you if the call will fail.

Comment: ok wait pls let me test it... and thanks for ur fast response

Comment: Hello bro thank very much for info eth_estimate. It is very time efficient to get gas estimation and to simulate transaction at same time. Also eth_call worked for me. The problem was, i made a mistake when i encode the ABI data.